# David sold to large corporations, "assists" employees and/or does things employees might find "distressing" -- do we have details?

Tags: character, prometheus

I would imagine that Davids would cost many millions of dollars each and do not do routine physical labor. Do they work as executives? Enforcers? Do we have any information from books, etc. about how Davids are utilized in non-space settings?

Here's the promotional video:

Comment: I'm sorry .... but the title is very unclear.  Is "assists" or "distasteful" from some quote?

Comment: yes, from a clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgJs7uluwlU -- I had assumed everyone had seen this "advert."

Comment: I don't remember every detail of a movie I last saw 8 years ago.  Thanks for including the clip ... this or quoting the movie will always help your question get an answer.

Comment: this clip is not from the movie. it is material they released to promote the film.

Comment: Even more reason to put more detail in your question.